# \image_class.as, Line 12 1026: Constructor functions must be instance methods

Tags: actionscript-3

package Classes
{

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import Classes.Image_SS;
import flash.events.Event;

public class image_class extends Sprite
{
    public static var ss:Image_SS = new Image_SS("3D_solid_surface_1",2);

    static public function image_class()
    {
        addChild(ss);
        ss.alpha = 0;
        ss.x = -2000;
        var tw1:my_Tween = new my_Tween(ss,"x",0,1,"Out");
        var tw2:my_Tween = new my_Tween(ss,"alpha",1,1,"Out");
    }
    static public function remove():void
    {
        removeChild(ss);
        /*
        var tw3:my_Tween = new my_Tween(ss,"x",2000,1,"In");
        var tw4:my_Tween = new my_Tween(ss,"alpha",0,1,"In");
        tw3.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCOM);
        function onCOM(e:Event):void
        {
            ss.alpha = 0;
            ss.x = -2000;               
        }
        */
    }
}
```

}
I don't know why it's not working.
Please someone tell me what's wrong here and what is the meaning of this erorr
Before i forgot i changed the function into public one and it didn't changed anything.

Comment: And there is nothing with same name in my fla library. If i remove the removeChild everything work good. But i realy do need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment.. (untested though, just based on code you posted)

```
//package Classes   
package 
{

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.*; //covers all events used in this code (inc mouse events) 
import Classes.Image_SS;

public class image_class extends Sprite
{
    public var ss:Image_SS = new Image_SS ("3D_solid_surface_1",2);

    public function image_class()
    {
        addChild(ss);

        //remove(); //do remove without mouse
        ss.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, remove); //for remove via mouse

        ss.alpha = 0;
        ss.x = -2000;
        var tw1:my_Tween = new my_Tween(ss,"x",0,1,"Out");
        var tw2:my_Tween = new my_Tween(ss,"alpha",1,1,"Out");
    }

    //public function remove():void //do without mouse click
    public function remove(event:MouseEvent):void //do via mouse click event
    {
        removeChild(ss);
        /*
        var tw3:my_Tween = new my_Tween(ss,"x",2000,1,"In");
        var tw4:my_Tween = new my_Tween(ss,"alpha",0,1,"In");
        tw3.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCOM);
        function onCOM(e:Event):void
        {
            ss.alpha = 0;
            ss.x = -2000;               
        }
        */
    }
}

} //close or end package
```

Answer (score 2):

The constructor (image_class) cannot be a static method. Remove static from its declaration

Comment: Ok now i have another erorr: call to a possibly undefined method removeChild on line 22

Comment: you call removeChild from a static method which is a class method as opposed to an instance method. A class is not a Sprite and does not have a method removeChild. If you were to remove the static keyword (thus making that method an instance method) then the removeChild would work on the class instance.

Comment: The class that i'm trying to remove is a sprite but sounds to me like i can't put the removeChild in a static function. So how can i tell a class to remove itself when user clicked on it.

Comment: it's a question of scope. In static methods the scope is the class itself which is not something you can add to a displaylist, in non static methods the scope is the instance of the class. you can keep a reference to an instance and use it in static methods like instance.removeChild() in instance methods that would be just removeChid()

Comment: BotMaster is right about that `static` keyword. It's not necessary here (at least from shown code). Remove all three and just keep it as `public function`. Now to run that remove function you just use the line `remove();` whenever/wherever you need it to happen. If its a click-based remove then you need a mouse event listener and relevant function type

Comment: i can't use an eventListener to remove my class. because it has lots of other buttons and mouse events inside of itself. and whenever i use click-based event listener to remove the class, the other clicked-based events which are inside just stop working.

Comment: The terms you are using are confusing and make what you are saying difficult to understand. "remove my class" is not possible in as3 for example. Then the rest of the sentence doesn't make sense either. If you remove something why would you care about what's inside not working anymore?

Comment: @FrostMaGE.. Are you saying when you `removeChild(ss)` you can still see "ss" on stage anyway? Or its correctly removed but the problem starts when you re-add "ss" a second time? If correctly removed it should be gone and there is nothing "inside" to see or click at that point

Comment: it doesn't run at all when i write the remove code there. By the way i managed to fix this using a for loop inside the class to remove all the children of the class.